# Change parent style when clicked on child node via event trigger

Tags: event-handling, javafx, javafx-2

I have a pane and a text field inside it. I have added mouselistener on pane, so that it changes color when user clicks on it(to mark selection). But the click event is not propagating from child to parent. Hence if I click on the text filed, my parent's color won't change. Is tried to trigger the click event on the parent, but cannot find any working core to trigger event manually.

Is there any way to do this via events, instead of repeating the code inside the handler?[image]

My Event listeners are on the pane(colored container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an event filter to the pane, instead of an event handler:

```
pane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        // update for selection...
    }
});
```